# Duplicate grub 2 on boot menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

While installing ubuntu 20.04 LTS desktop with a bootable usb, I used easyBCD (free version) on windows to add/manage the boot menu. I had chosen the root partition of linux ( / ) to write the boot  while installation. I now have three boot options with a windows and two linux (a duplicate which I add inadvertently in easyBCD). I tried removing the duplicate linux boot menu with easyBCD and Grub Customizer without success. The duplicate linux boot menu is bothering me and I want it gone.

Any suggestions and help is highly appreciated. Thanks in anticipation!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computer in this question has 2 different boot menus, one of which has grub as one of its boot entries. To remove duplicate entries in the boot menu that leads to the GRUB boot menu run EasyBCD on Windows.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. however, it did not solved it as my issue was with the boot (duplicate) entry menu to Grub 2. Here, one of the duplicate boot menu leads to the Grub 2. I retried with easyBCD on windows and luckily it got resolved. Perhaps an oversight on my earlier try. Thanks again!